# force gcc to compile when stack-overflow is detected

Tags: c, gcc, stack, stack-overflow, gcc-warning

How can i force gcc to compile a program in which i declare an array of unsigned integers that is bigger than my ram - without getting the warning warning: "integer overflow in expression"?

eg. i have 8gb of ram and i want do declare an array of 8.5gb.

### edit:

thanks everybody, i figured out that the problem wasnt with the datatype but with some preprocessor stuff. it took me quite a while though. :)
i wrote

```
#define GIBI 1073741824
#define ARRAYSIZE 2*GIBI
```

and obviously the compiler didnt like that.

Comment: Why would you like to have an array bigger than your ram if you couldn't even fill it?

Comment: Warnings are warnings, not errors. (There is an option to treat warnings as errors or not.)

Comment: @BlackBear: Here are a few reasons why one would want to allocate more memory than one has RAM:  1. Virtual memory means you can have more memory available than you have RAM.  2.  You may be compiling a program that will run on a machine that has more RAM than your development machine.

Comment: @Kristopher Johnson: It has nothing to do with RAM size. The stack size (or, more exactly, the address range reserved for stack) is limited from the start, and the program will crash trying to `alloca()` more space than the stack. Howerer, in this question the problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`integer overflow in expression` isn't a stack overflow, it means that GCC has detected that the result of your expression is causing an integral overflow in the lvalue you're assigning it to. For instance, if you try to `malloc` something like `INT_MAX * 2`, that expression will cause an integral overflow. If you cast it to a `size_t`, you should be warning-free:

```
void *myvar = malloc((size_t) INT_MAX * 2);
```

`size_t` is, of course, platform-dependent, and you *could* also overflow that if you can't represent the size of the block you want to allocate in `sizeof(size_t)` bits. Basically, make sure you're using a type capable of representing the amount of memory you want to allocate and that it's compatible with `size_t` (since that's what `malloc()` expects, according to `stdlib.h`).

Comment: `size_t` cannot "overflow". It's unsigned, so it wraps, but formally that's not overflow. :-)

Comment: Wikipedia says "an integer overflow occurs when an arithmetic operation attempts to create a numeric value that is larger than can be represented within the available storage space"... basically exactly what I described. If you've got a more authoritative source, then please enlighten me :)

Answer (score 5):

That error message is not saying that you're going to run out of stack, though you will. It's saying that the number is too big to represent in `size_t`.  Make sure you're compiling for a 64-bit target.

Furthermore, don't do that.  If you need to allocate gigantic amounts of RAM, do it with `malloc`, not the stack.  Or, better yet, with `mmap`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure that `"integer overflow in expression"?` does *not* mean that you are overflowing the stack but rather you are doing some math that may potentially overflow a signed integer which is **Undefined Behavior**. It would help if you paste the line the warning is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to allocate more memory than you have RAM you might do some research on memory mapped files. That way you won't need to worry about the physical memory in your machine (of which you don't have access to all 8GB anyway)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx